# Playing Planescape Torment without RMB

Tags: android, planescape-torment

I recently became aware of an open-source implementation of Bioware's Infinity Engine called [GemRB](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start). My favourite part is that it supports pretty much all platforms, including Android!

But here's the trouble: I've got a Samsung Galaxy S, meaning I don't have a physical keyboard, just touch controls. It's nearly impossible to issue a right-click command (the force-pressing or 2 finger gestures are mostly unreliable).

Is it possible to play Planescape Torment without ever right-clicking?

Comment: Could someone with a bit more reputation please edit in the tags GemRB, PlanescapeTorment and/or Bioware?

Comment: I added Planescpae Torment, I believe the other two tags you asked for are too specific

Comment: Bioware's a bad tag in that it doesn't contribute anything to the discussion that planescape-torment doesn't already. GemRB is a trickier case.

Comment: Honestly, this strikes me as the sort of thing the folks making GemRB should've thought of. Two-finger tap for right click or whatever seems like a no brainer.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz There's a few options like two-finger tap, force-tap and tap-and-hold, but none of them are very reliable. I can only get a right-click to register about once in five tries, and it gets frustrating very fast...

Comment: That sounds more like a crummy device than crummy software, tbqh. :(

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz For what it's worth, I've played Osmos on my phone and it's got two-finger and three-finger gestures, and they're all crisp and a delight to use. So I know it's not the device, and I'm fairly certain it's not me :)

Comment: Doesn't that tablet have a USB port? If so, you could plug a mouse in.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to play Planescape Torment without ever right-clicking? No.

Right-Click opens a context menu which is needed for interacting with the game world.